# Sort Core_store_group by id not name

Tags: multistore

I am creating a multistore magento site. In my store switcher(NOT store-view) stores are listed by name as default. But for me its important to be listed by core_store_group_id from smaller to bigger.
How can i sort it in my store swithcher phtml
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you using the default store switcher, you could check out `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Switch.php`. The method you are looking for is either `getGroups` or `getStores`

What you can do is update your layout to include a custom block which extends the class `Mage_Page_Block_Switch`

Eg:

```
<block type="custom/page_switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
```

In that block, you will override one of the methods i mention, and then its really just a matter of ordering the array as you like, using plain php `ksort`

Comment: I am really new in magento and beginer level of web programing.
I appreciate if you give me all details what i can do.
I used the below way to show my stores in header:
http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-showing-store-selector-switcher-in-header-and-footer/